# Bootstrap does not load on angular 6

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having problems trying to load bootstrap on Angular 6, I already installed bootstrap (`npm install bootstrap`) and declared it on angular.json but still doesn't work. Is there any other thing I should do? Im also using sass, does that interfere in something?

Here's the angular.json

```
    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "test-itau": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "projectType": "application",
          "prefix": "app",
          "schematics": {
            "@schematics/angular:component": {
              "styleext": "scss"
            }
          },
          "targets": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/test-itau",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                "assets": [
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/assets"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.css",
                  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                ],
                "scripts": []
              },
//more code...
```

Comment: What exactly isn’t working?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure why that doesn't work, there's a few things that you can do to get bootstrap themes on your site.

If you wanted to use a CDN, you could add a `link` element to the head of your `index.html` file.

Alternatively, if you could do it how Angular material does, and import it from your `src/styles.scss` file. Like so:

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Edit:
[Here's an example of it working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zltxeu)

Comment: I've tried both but still doesnt work, I would love to use the cdn link but I put it there and nothing changes. The import i forgot to mention tha i've already put it on the scss file

Comment: Do any styles work from your `styles.scss` file? Did Angular create that file or did you?

Comment: @RenêSilvaLima I added a stackblitz example for you to refer to

Comment: I changed it from styles.css to styles.scss and update the styles on angular.json to styles.scss and no, I've just tested it and the styles on it doent work

Comment: Is your `angular.json` different to what is posted? Because in that file it still says `styles.css`

Comment: Maybe try and create a new project? Issue the command `ng new testing-bootstrap --style=scss` to have it configured with scss to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I'll try it, thank you very much for trying to help me :)